Почему окно не появляется сразу?
Нужно сделать так, чтобы окно появлялось одновременно с началом звукового сигнала. Но в моем примере сначала срабатывает звуковой сигнал, а уже после него появляется окно.
from tkinter import *
import winsound
 
window = Tk()            
window.title("Test")     
window.geometry("200x50")   

def myfunc():
    winsound.Beep(500,3000)
    
window.after(0, myfunc)
window.mainloop()

Как сделать так, чтобы эти два события срабатывали одновременно? Чтобы окно появлялось одновременно со звуковым сигналом?

Beep блокирует работу основного потока. Либо сделайте небольшую паузу (10-50 мс), чтобы он выполнялся после создания окна, либо запускайте в отдельном потоке.
